# Matlab, plot inside a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, time

could you please help me with this:

The level of pollution Pt evolves overtime according to Pt+1=e0.02Pt. Suppose that
P0=5. Using a loop, compute the evolution of P for 100 periods. Then plot the results.

I have tried many different ways like:

```
for p = 5:1:100; x = p; y =  exp(0.02)*x; plot(x,y,'-'); drawnow; 
pt = (1:120); for p = 5:1:100;  pt =exp(0.02)*p; plot(p, pt, '-' );drawnow; end
```

without any success. thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Your problem is not MATLAB related. Your problem is that you didn't understand what is asked from you. You need to plot population over time, not population at a moment vs population at a previous moment. Suggestion: 1) do some calculation steps by hand, 2) see the pattern, 3) implement that calculation pattern in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to realise, what the problem is. You need to calculate next steps basing on previous calculations. So the code should be lihe this:

```
p=zeros(100,1);
p(1)=5;
for t = 2:1:100;
    p(t)=exp(0.02)*p(t-1);
end
plot(p,'.'); 
xlabel('time')
ylabel('pollution')
title('pollution over time')
```